# "Connected backward" or "connected backwards"

Tags: word-choice

I have to write this phrase:

> An electric motor is basically a generator connected backwards.

Someone that is not a natural English speaker said the correct is `connected backward`.

Which one is the correct?

Comment: You will find numerous websites addressing this question, including; https://grammarist.com/usage/backward-vs-backwards/ (indicating that you should opt for **backwards**.) although several sites point to a difference between US and UK use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both *correct*. It's a matter of style and preference. (As well as, to some degree, what country you are from.)

From [*Oxford Dictionaries*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/backward):

> In most adverbial uses backward and backwards are interchangeable: the car rolled slowly backward and the car rolled slowly backwards are both equally acceptable. In North American English backward tends to be preferred to backwards, while in British English it is the other way round. As an adjective, on the other hand, the standard form is backward rather than backwards: uses such as a backwards glance (as opposed to a backward glance) are unusual

In your sentence, it's being used as an adverb, so there isn't a clear preference for the singular version.